# Back up from Multiple Sources

Tags: windows, backup, external-hard-drive, drive-letter

I have several separate copies of my OS volume taken over various points in time, but now want to set up a cleaner, scheduled backup strategy.  I could simply start regularly backing up the current volume contents, and I will do at least that, but I would also like to retain the history from the other earlier copies as well.  Finally I don't want to use anything super sophisticated, so probably just the vanilla Windows 10 backup utility.  Is there any way of using the standard Win10 backup to grab these previous copies and treat them as previous backups?

Also, most of the copies are on separate, old drives, so I had thought to just change the drive letters to C: and back up from there, to trick it into thinking they were all from C:, but I can't change the real C: to something else.  So my current approach would be to copy the current contents to a safe space elsewhere, then copy all the oldest copy back into C:, back that up, and repeat for each newer copy till I get back to copying the current contents back to C: and backing that up.  That's a world of pain I'd like to avoid if possible, so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Handy Backup](https://www.handybackup.net/system-backup.shtml) to organize your system copy collection. (Yes, it is commercial, but it has a 30-day trial period to test and enjoy… haha!) Unfortunately, I see no way to use your old Win10 backup copies as system images. Can you copy all these copies into one big library and rename/retag all these copies to build a time-stamped array?